# Updating table in a sample crud example in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJs and while building my first CRUD example I face a problem in the update function; all the other function are correct except the update.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Sort and Filter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Age
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        Birth Day
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
                    <td ng-bind: "person.name">{{ person.name }}</td>
                    <td ng-bind: "person.age">{{ person.age }}</td>
                    <td ng-bind: "person.bday">{{ person.bday }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" ng-click="edit(person,persons,indexOf(person))" value="edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" ng-click="del(indexOf(person))" value="delete" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tbody>
                <!-- This table is to enter data-->
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Name: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Age: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="age" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Birth Day: </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="bday" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" ng-click="btnclk()" value="Save" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" ng-click="btnupd(name,age,bday)" value="Update" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
    angular.module('sortApp', [])



        $scope.persons = [{
            name: 'Seif',
            age: '15',
            bday: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Zied',
            age: '14',
            bday: 4
        }, {
            name: 'Meriem',
            age: '17',
            bday: 7
        }, {
            name: 'Jaber',
            age: '2',
            bday: 6
        }];

        $scope.del = function(index) {
            $scope.persons.splice(index, 1);
        };
        $scope.btnclk = function() {
            if (!$scope.name) {
                alert("Enter Name");
            } else if (!$scope.age) {
                alert("Enter Age");
            } else if (!$scope.bday) {
                alert("Enter Birth Day");
            } else {
                $scope.persons.push({
                    'name': $scope.name,
                    'age': $scope.age,
                    'bday': $scope.bday
                });
                $scope.name = '';
                $scope.age = '';
                $scope.bday = '';
            }
        };
        var key;
        $scope.edit = function(person, index) {
            key = index;
            $scope.name = person.name;
            $scope.age = person.age;
            $scope.bday = person.bday;

        };
        $scope.btnupd = function(name, age, bday) {
            $scope.persons[key].name = name;
            $scope.persons[key].age = age;
            $scope.persons[key].bday = bday;
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.age = '';
            $scope.bday = '';

        };
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. While calling edit function you are passing 3 params. So your `key` variable is getting set to `persons` that you are passing.
2. There is no need to pass name, age, bday to btnupd(). You can use the $scope variables instead. like $scope.persons[key].name = **$scope.** name;
3. Instead of defining `var key` I would prefer defining `$scope.key` and use it that way